# Version of Ext JS used by AEM 6.1

Tags: extjs, adobe, aem

Which version of Ext JS library does AEM 6.1 use? Is there a direct way/console to find this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses `v3.4.0` of ExtJS on top of which the AEM Widget Library is built. You can find the details at `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/release-notes.html`

The following Note is also available at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/widgets.html

> Adobe Experience Manager is built upon ExtJS 3.4.0.