# What version of ExJs does CQ5.5 use? Where can I find a good tutorial of the CQ5 version of ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, aem

I would also want to know whether is will be of any use of not if I learn ExtJs?
I am a CQ5/Java developer. I work more on the OSGi level. But now the requests for custom components is too much so I am struggling with the ExtJs part that involves custom widget... Will learning ExtJs help me as a developer?

(Please provide helpful links)

Comment: You could try to find out from browser console. [`Ext.getVersion()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext-method-getVersion) should be available from 4.1.1 through 6.0.1. I sincerely hope the ExtJS version used is not older than that.

Comment: @Alexander I think it is 2.x. This is what I have heard. I am trying to find tutorials for that but I am getting none. These Sencha guys have disabled all old links

Comment: Welcome to the club :-). The only documentation we have is API reference: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html

Answer (score 3):

CQ 5.5 also uses v3.4.0 of ExtJS on top of which the AEM Widget Library is built. You can find the release notes at `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/release-notes.html`

The following Note is also available at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/widgets.html

```
CQ 5.5 is built upon ExtJS 3.4.0.
```

A similar question was answered 2 days back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553557/version-of-ext-js-used-by-aem-6-1/35555343#35555343).

Comment: Where can I learn ExtJs 3.4.0? Will it help me?

Comment: There is a bunch of examples posted, you can learn from studying code: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/

Answer (score 0):

The best source of info on AEM widgets is https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html . I think there are some differences between AEM version and vanilla ExtJS.