# Adobe Experience Manager support for ExtJS

Tags: extjs, aem

When will Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) remove support for ExtJS? Even in version 6.3, there is still a large number of interfaces that still use ExtJS. Has Adobe announced a specific schedule for its removal?

I'm specifically wondering if/when we can anticipate the removal of ExtJS from a future version of AEM.

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS support would be removed in 2019. Quoting from the docs

> Adobe is planning to deprecate the Classic UI in AEM in April 2018.
>   The 2018 release of AEM will still contain the Classic UI as it is
>   part of current AEM release. Following that, Adobe is planning to
>   remove the Classic UI from AEM in April 2019.

AEM 6.3 still has the classic UI to help customers who are upgrading from older versions of AEM to 6.3. However, they recommend switching to the new UI as soon as possible.

More information on this is available at [User Interface Recommendations](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/deploy/best-practices/ui-recommendations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the solution provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553557/version-of-ext-js-used-by-aem-6-1).

```
AEM 6.3 also use ExtJS 3.4.0.
```